# Deserialize simple XML array object in C# for WCF service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xsd, deserialization

For 3 days I've been facing the same problem and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Context: I am creating a new WCF service for a fixed XML.

Problem: it looks like the deserialisation of the XML goes wrong. I do get the `data` object back but without the property `items` filled.

Tried so far:

- Creating the C# class with xsd 4.0 (currently used in the WCF project) and 4.7.
- Adding multiple attributes like:

  ```
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0"), XmlSerializerFormat].
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("attr", IsNullable = false)]
  ```

  to the `Items` property

This is the xml I am going to recieve:

```
<spml:data xmlns:spml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
    <attr name="mailone" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value>xxxx@gmail.com</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="mailtwo" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value>xxxx@gmail.com</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="mailthree" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <value>xxxx@gmail.com</value>
    </attr>
</spml:data>
```

With the xsd (4.0 currently used in the wcf project for other objects) I get this c# class from the xsd:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.33440.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class data
{
    private attr[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attr")]
    public attr[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class attr
{

    private string valueField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this program to simplify the mapping problem:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlDeserializer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
            data data;

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(PATH))
            {
                data = (data)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this console application with the C# class in the same project and debug on data you will get a data object back with `items = null`.

Can someone had me in the right direction?

EDIT: it has to do with the namespaces: I removed all the namespaces in the XML and c# object and it worked.

Kind regards,
Pieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works.  I changed the namespaces :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
            data d = (data)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class data
    {
        private attr[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "attr", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core")]
        public attr[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class attr
    {

        private string valueField;

        private string nameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tested this and it worked. To my surprise i converted my xml to class with the special paste in visualstudio and it gave me a class that worked aswell. Something was messed up in the xsd tool. The thing i learned: I fully trusted on the xsd generated file and did not think it was a fault. Next time i will be more critical... Thanks for helping me out